# How do I cargo expand a non-compiling runtime?

Tags: runtime, cargo

`cargo expand` is a very useful tool to see the expanded macros that a runtime generates, but if the runtime doesn't compile then it does not output anything.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Quite often I have found that if you run `SKIP_WASM_BUILD=1 cargo expand` then it will expand the code even if there's some compile errors.